# Maven 3 - Variables in packed Submodules

Tags: maven-3

Dear stackoverflow community

I have a problem with a maven 3 project. Basically i have a Parent Pom X, a child Pom Y and a module Z within the Y Pom. POM Y and Module Z are packed compiled and stored in my local maven repository. Z points to the parent version with a variable defined in the Parent Pom X. So everthing compiles and installs fine with the right version number defined in Parent Pom X

Now my Problem: if i use Z as dependency in a POM B (which is also a child of parent Pom X) with the version variable defined in Parent Pom X it fails because Module Z does not resolve the version variable during maven build.

Error: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for Z:jar:someProjectVersion: Failure to find Y:pom:${someProjectVersionVariable}

Update: Here are the (simplified) poms:

Parent Pom:

```
<groupId>someProject</groupId>
<artifactId>someProject-parent</artifactId>
<version>5.3.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<properties>
<child.version>5.3.3-SNAPSHOT</child.version>
</properties>
```

Child Y POM

```
<parent>
    <groupId>someProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>someProject-parent</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../someProject-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<modules>
    <module>moduleZ</module>
</module> 
</modules>
<artifactId>someProject-Child</artifactId>
<name>someProject Child Name</name>
<version>${child.version}</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

Module Z POM:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>someProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>someProject-child</artifactId>
    <version>${child.version}</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<artifactId>someProjectModule</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Module Z</name>
```

Child Bs POM:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>someProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>someProject-parent</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../someProject-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>someProject-Child-B</artifactId>
<name>someProject Child Name B</name>
<version>${child.version}</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependency>
    <groupId>someProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>someProjectModule</artifactId>
    <version>${child.version}</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Now building Child Y is no Problem, with no errors
Building Child B results in:

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for someProjectModule:jar:5.3.3-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find someProject-Child:pom:${child.version}
```

Comment: Might be better to show your poms to help us understand. You can always cut out parts that shouldn't matter, it's just a bit hard to know if the issue might be in the POMs themselves

Comment: i updated my question, hope its clearer now..

Comment: Don't know if this is more than just a typo, but I see variations of ${child.version} and ${child.Version}.

Comment: sorry its a typo.. this is just a simplified version of my setup which i wrote here